# JavaScript convert string into HTML element

Tags: javascript

I have javascript string with HTML elements. I want to display these elements on page but not in string form.

```
 var stars = a;
        if (stars == 5){
            return '<i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i>'
        }
```

So how it is possible to convert this string?

Comment: Do you want to return a string or a DOM element? If you want the put this somewhere, put it in the DOM directly using `var safestring = $('<div>').text(unsafestring).html();` or use the inner html property and put the element directly in the DOM (if you dont want to use jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `innerHTML` property of an element.

E.g.

```
let element = document.getElementById('myElement');

element.innerHTML = "<i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i>"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use insertAdjacentHTML

```
const divInString = '<div class="todo">Stuff</div>'
const parentOfDiv = document.querySelector(".parent")
parentOfDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd",divInString)
```

I was looking for a solution for this problem as well and this is what solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the innerHTML property to add the string as elements to the document. And you have to use the correct quotes in the string. Your string is not valid.

```js
var stars = 5;
if (stars == 5) {
  document.getElementById('body').innerHTML += '<i class="fas fa-star">a</i><i class="fas fa-star">a</i><i class="fas fa-star">a</i><i class="fas fa-star">a</i><i class="fas fa-star">a</i>'
}
```

```css
.fas
{
background-color:green
}
```

```html
<body id="body"></body>
```